# Cannot focus using jQuery load() with modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, load, focus

I am using jQuery load() to add a modal that contains a form. Any attempts to focus on the first field have failed. My code looks like this:

The file foo.html contains:

```
<div id='standardModal' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
            <div id='standardModalBody' class='modal-body'>
                <form id='addRecord'>
                    <div class='form-group' id='intTypeD'>
                        <label for='intType'>Type</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='intType'>
                        <small id='intTypeM' class='text-danger'></small>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript calls:

```
$('#screens').load('foo.html', function() {
  $.getJSON('addRecord_initialize.php', function (result) {
     ...
  }.always(function () {
     $('#standardModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

No I've tried to add

```
$('#addRecord input:text, #addRecord textarea').first().focus();
```

or

```
$('#intType').focus();
```

both right of the beginning of the function that is called when load is completed, and after modal('show') - but all 4 variants don't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal needs some time to open, and the browser needs some time to reflow, especially when there is a transition. So, You can set the focus after a certain amount of time by using a simple `setTimeout`, or - even better - by using the events provided by Your modal plugin.

In Your `.always` - assuming You are using the Bootstrap modal (if not, please specify otherwise):

```
$('#standardModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#intType').trigger('focus')
})
```

Moreover, here is the reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

> Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute
>   has no effect in Bootstrap modals. To achieve the same effect, use
>   some custom JavaScript.

If this won't work either, You should change strategy: keep in Your main page the stub for an empty modal, then fill just only the content `div` by using the ajax request. This way, You will have the event handlers and all other plugin stuff always available on Your main page.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use JQuery here, you can simply use HTML.

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='intType' autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addRecord input:text, #addRecord textarea').first().focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='standardModal' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div id='standardModalBody' class='modal-body'>
        <form id='addRecord'>
          <div class='form-group' id='intTypeD'>
            <label for='intType'>Type</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='intType'>
            <small id='intTypeM' class='text-danger'></small>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, this worked:

```
$('#standardModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#intType').trigger('focus')
})
```

Strangely, I thought I had covered that possible problem by waiting in the debugger, but obviously it's not the same.

autofocus has a problem on most browsers, that's why I started to use the jQuery option.

Thanks again, case closed.